# What is wrong with this code? Keeps getting application defined error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Keep prompting application defined error, I do no think there is anything wrong

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""Subtotal for ""& Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Address)"
```

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve here?  CONCATENATE takes multiple arguments but you're passing only one (if you fix your error).  Seems like you're using both CONCATENATE and `&` when you only need one of those

Comment: @TimWilliams I realize I have to use concatenate as that cell is linked to another cell. So if the other cell value changes, the value in Cells(salesNo + 1, 5) will change respectively

Comment: The cell also has additional string so what the outcome I would like is for example =CONCATENATE("Subtotal for "&C16) so if the value of C16 changes, the formula will change respectively. But i can't seem to implement that with variables included.

Comment: @TimWilliams Also, this is done with a userform included

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Formula = _
      "=""Subtotal for "" & " & Cells(salesNo - 1, 3).Address
```

Comment: Not the intended outcome, as the value will be placed and not the cell itself. For example, I want the formula to show C19 and not "Company A".

Answer (score 0):

## ADDRESS in Excel

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Formula _
    = "=""Subtotal for ""&ADDRESS(" & salesNo - 1 & ",3)"
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Formula = "=" & Chr(34) _
    & "Subtotal for " & Chr(34) & "&ADDRESS(" & salesNo - 1 & ",3)"
```

To get rid of the $ signs:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Formula _
    = "=""Subtotal for ""&ADDRESS(" & salesNo - 1 & ",3,4)"
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Formula = "=" & Chr(34) _
    & "Subtotal for " & Chr(34) & "&ADDRESS(" & salesNo - 1 & ",3,4)"
```

### EDIT

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Formula _
    = "=""Subtotal for ""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & salesNo - 1 & ",3,4))"
```

or

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(salesNo + 1, 5).Formula = "=" & Chr(34) _
    & "Subtotal for " & Chr(34) & "&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & salesNo - 1 & ",3,4))"
```

Comment: I am confused, so which one would you recommend me to use in general? And why does the last 2 codes have "4" at the end? Thx in advance

Comment: @beginnercoder123: The first is absolute e.g. $C$4 (when you copy it it stays $C$4) and the second is relative e.g. C4 (when you copy it to e.g. D column it becomes D4). I don't think it matters in your case because you just want to show the address.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation! May I ask what is Chr(34) about?

Comment: @beginnercoder123: 34 is the code number of double quotes ("). In Excel it is =Char(34). Every character has a code number. In Excel try e.g.  =Code("A") and it will return the character code.

Comment: First code, does not work. It shows ' Subtotal for $C$19 ' instead, I want it to show the value of C19 and not C19 itself

Comment: An example of what I want the formula to be is this 
 =CONCATENATE("Subtotal for "&C16) but with variables. Is it not possible to do so?

Comment: It worked!! But I have another issue now, since the formula is replaced with these set of codes. I have another button that searches for this cell but it will not work as the previous code was "Subtotal for " usernameComboBox.Value. Thus, is it possible to search for the value of the cell directly For eg.  Subtotal for CompanyA instead of searching the formula which is the problem currently For eg. ="Subtotal for " ""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & salesNo - 1 & ",3,4))"

Comment: I hope you understand what I am trying to explain, as VBA seems so difficult and complicated for me

Comment: @beginnercoder123: No idea. You show me the exact formula which should be in Excel and I'll try to translate it into VBA

Comment: Is not a formula, is just a code that searches for the text for example in C16, but now since it is replaced with a formula that is  ="Subtotal for " ""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & salesNo - 1 & ",3,4))" it will search for the formula itself which is that set of code itself. Instead I want it to search for the text of the cell in C16 in which is Subtotal for Company A to make my old code work. As the previous code was "Subtotal for " & usernamComboBox.Value.

Comment: ="Subtotal for " ""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(" & salesNo - 1 & ",3,4))" gives the Text ' Subtotal for Company A' , and "Subtotal for " usernameComboBox.Value. also gives the text of ' Subtotal for Company A' , hence I would like to search for the text Company A and not the formula on the cell to make my code work. Hope you understand what I am trying to convey.